# Is the use of term "Democracy" in the moderator elections correct?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, rules

Recently it came to my attention the Moderators Elections on Stack Overflow.

There was the pompous (in my opinion) term "democracy"
since "we believe that the community should choose their moderators",
etc. if I recall them correctly.

Democracy is not an abstract term and denotes a political system that
people decide and make terms for their own interests. Governance is exerted by their representatives only.

This is an "a la carte" approach of democracy since people only
elect moderators but moderators should adhere to the "legislation"
posed by the "state" / company.

There are guidelines about many things on Stack Overflow, but these are created by the site owners and not from the community (as I can judge...).

Furthermore, I have seen in the past petitions of some kind about changing terms on Stack Overflow, but for good or worse they were declined (like for instance allowing someone to contact someone else via messages like in comments - not saying that this is good or bad, but I use this to denote that decisions are not made by the people (or their representatives - moderators) but from the admin team).

This certainly does not adhere to a democratic society by any means.

Perhaps the use of this term should be reconsidered and something else maybe used in the future.

Comment: or perhaps you're attaching too much importance to it

Comment: OP has a point though - moderators don't make the rules, they enforce them. So it's more like we get to choose our police officers.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for the "something else" to be used in the future?

Comment: Any democratically appointed official must adhere to the rules laid out in the constitution.  Anything is possible in the Internet age, if you don't like the constitution then you can create your own state.

Comment: Related: [What form of government does StackExchange resemble?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/320/101)

Comment: They aren't necessarily saying that Stack Overflow is a democratic society. They're saying that the elections are democratic. Which they are, for all reasonable definitions of that extremely nebulous term: "the citizens exercise power directly or *elect representatives from among themselves*". You might argue, as people have done endlessly about the United States political system, that it would be more accurate to use the term "republic", but seriously, no one cares.

Comment: I have to disagree  that there is such thing as a constitution in SO.
Being laconic ,  constitutions are drafted and voted by national assemblies which in this case would be the communities. No such thing here. Of course you could easily create another community, declare your "constitution" and find your people. I dont know though if this can be called democracy. Thanks everyone for the insight and your opinions.

Comment: Meta is a sort of national assembly...

Comment: *constitutions are drafted and voted by national assemblies which in this case would be the communities. No such thing here.* - Area 51, beta sites, and as Yannis pointed out, Meta. But I agree with Cody that they were only referring to the election itself as democratic, not the entire site.

Comment: `There are guidelines about many things on Stack Overflow, but these are created by the site owners and not from the community` But that's where you're wrong.  Virtually all of the sites guidelines *are* based on what the community wants.  They're *not* dictated by the company.  There are some exceptions here and there, but by and large, they don't have much influence on what the guidelines are, or how they're enforced.

Comment: A benevolent dictatorship whose simian enforcers are elected by the community.

Answer (score 27):

The system is a peculiar mix of a meritocracy, oligarchy and constitutional democracy.

The meritocratic side is that only those with a minimum of rep get to vote. And it takes even more rep, and a number of badges, to be a candidate.

The "constitutional democracy" is that there are basic principles by which Stack Overflow adheres. Direct messages were declined because it would violate some of these core principles - keeping as much public as possible, and focusing on content rather than individuals. These guiding principles overrule the public desire.

And the oligarchy is that the rules are only there if Stack Overflow, the company, agrees on them. They have shown an active interest in our opinions and often implemented the changes we asked for. But ultimately, it's up to them what happens.
There is a balance of power, though - Stack Overflow wants its community to stay. If they diverge too far away from what we, as a community, desire - then its best contributors will leave. Or establish something else. They are well aware that Stack Overflow itself was born in protest against another site (Experts Exchange), and that they themselves may become obsolete if they alienate us like EE upset them.

And finally... moderators don't make the rules. Moderators have been called glorified janitors and that's actually quite accurate. They work to keep the site clean and resolve conflicts. They're more like police officers than democratic representatives.

So - it's not really a democracy. On the other hand, the "government" (Stack Overflow, the company) listens pretty well to its "people" (the community). I've seen democratically elected representatives in real-life elections, who once in office cared a lot less about their voters than Stack Overflow cares about its community.